# Position box in firefox extension

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, xul

Trying my hand at some simple firefox extensions...

I am trying to create a second "bar" the width of the browser window directly above the default status bar at the bottom of the browser.

Placing a simple hbox element in my overlay places a second "bar" below the default status bar but I cant seem to find a way to move it about. I have tried "insertbefore='status-bar'" and such.

I have been searching for a while but cant seem to find an answer to this seemingly simple problem...

UPDATE...heres my overlay in psuedocode(im not at my machine right now)...

```
<overlay>

  //this is where i want to do a second "bar" above the status bar
  <hbox>
    //random text in here is displayed in bar properly but its below the default bar
    // tried "insertbefore='status-bar'" in the hbox tag...but this had no effect..
  </hbox> 

  //default status bar...i placed a button here...
  <statusbar id="status-bar">
    //button element goes here and is placed on right side of default status bar
    // this works as expected
  </statusbar>

</overlay>
```

Comment: It would help to post a snippet from your overlay.xul. You need to put your bar as a child of the parent of the main Firefox status bar. I don't remember exactly what that is, but use DOM Inspector to find out.

Comment: Ok added some psuedocode of what I have been trying. Everything works as expected except for the positioning of the hbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said, you need to find the parent of the status bar, using DOM Inspector (I think it's the "bottom box"), then put your box as a child of that element.

Comment: Thank you. I didnt get a chance to try it yet but it sounds like this is the answer I was looking for. Finally this is starting to make sense to me. Most of the tutorials I have found are very basic in terms of XUL so its been tough to get started.